# LInear Regression - approaching models with Date as variable

Tags: r, regression

This question is an extension to an earlier question [Linear regression - date as dummy variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425585/linear-regression-date-as-dummy-variable/425587?noredirect=1#comment794625_425587).  I still have some doubts in selecting the best modeling approach.

Autoregressive would be better, but I am using regression as an alternative.

If the initial training data used is the one showed below (in `R`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)
data <- structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), Qty = c(8286, 
14804, 8540, 8150, 7410, 7940, 10337, 15306, 7554, 15778, 22091, 
28390, 17278, 42589, 11393, 14011, 6726, 27269, 16008, 42521, 
17043, 23212, 13752, 22412, 45143, 22428, 16398, 30901, 15760, 
23674, 9625, 25319, 34241, 42536, 32043, 62265)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))



test <- structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
   .Label = "2019", class = "factor"), 
    Month = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
    "7"), class = "factor")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
qtytest <- c(13943, 50692, 19538, 54282, 4986, 12872)
```

In the first case, from the 'Date' column, 'Year' and 'Month' are extracted and converted to factor to build the model

```
model <- lm(Qty ~ Year + Month, data = data)
summary(model)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.5208049
forcastdata <- predict(model, newdata = test)
accuracy(forcastdata, x = qtytest)[, "MAPE"]
[1] 312.0962
```

With second case, the original dates (monthly data) are scaled by taking the difference from the minimum date value for each 'year'

```
 data2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 
16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 
17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 
17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 
17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897), class = "Date"), Qty = c(8286, 
14804, 8540, 8150, 7410, 7940, 10337, 15306, 7554, 15778, 22091, 
28390, 17278, 42589, 11393, 14011, 6726, 27269, 16008, 42521, 
17043, 23212, 13752, 22412, 45143, 22428, 16398, 30901, 15760, 
23674, 9625, 25319, 34241, 42536, 32043, 62265), Month = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L))



 test2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 
18048, 18078), class = "Date"), Month = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

 data2 %>% group_by(Year = year(Date)) %>% mutate(dateInterval = 100 *(as.integer(Date)  - first(as.integer(Date)))/first(as.integer(Date))) %>% ungroup %>% select(dateInterval, Month, Qty) -> data2


test2 %>%  group_by(Year = year(Date)) %>% mutate(dateInterval = 100 *(as.integer(Date)  - first(as.integer(Date)))/first(as.integer(Date))) %>% ungroup %>% select(dateInterval, Month) -> test2


model2 <- lm(Qty ~ dateInterval + Month, data = data2)
summary(model2)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.2633624
forcastdata2 <- predict(model2, newdata = test2)
 accuracy(forcastdata2, x = qtytest)[, "MAPE"]
 [1] 72.56004
```

The accuracy improved with second model, however, the adjusted r-squared decreased to half.  Do you have any thoughts about which way to proceed?

Also, I am looking for any other approaches that would be best suitable for this situation.

Comment: R-squared changes just by changing the number of independent variables, it is not a good measure of goodness of fit.

Comment: @user2974951  Thanks.  Among the approaches showed here, which one would be more correct?

Comment: Your $R^2$ values are from the data the model was fit to, while your MAPE seems to be from holdout data. Values calculated from holdout data are preferable, as they as less biased by overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

Regression against time can often be a very poor alternative to model identification strategies incorporating an ARIMA model with possible level shifts and possible time trend predictors.  The reason is that your are specifying the form of the model ( no pulses , no level shifts , no arima  , no changes in trend rather than determining the form of the model via analytics as is illustrated here  https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf which CAN culminate in the regression against time model that you are specifying. This approach requires equally spaced temporal data while your regression approach against time does not thus you may have no choice.

An initial glance suggest a few pulses ( one time unusual values ) which if untreated can effect estimated parameters.